# How do I use Data Binding with reused layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

Let's say I have the following layout files:

**first_layout.xml**

```
<layout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
      <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/title_one"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="First layout title"/>
      <include
          layout="@layout/reusable_layout"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**second_layout.xml**

```
<layout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
      <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/title_two"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Second layout title"/>
      <include
          layout="@layout/reusable_layout"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**reusable_layout.xml**

```
<layout>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text_to_replace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="replace me"/>
</layout>
```

...and that I have two different ViewModels (FirstLayoutViewModel and SecondLayoutViewModel, each with a different String property). I want to use Data Binding to bind each ViewModel's string property to the `text_to_replace` element in `reusable_layout.xml`.

How can I do this? Normally, I would declare a variable in a `<data>` tag and assign the type to the appropriate ViewModel but how can I do this if the layout (`reusable_layout.xml`) is being used multiple times? How will it know which ViewModel type to use?

In this example, I could just use a different TextView for the first_layout and second_layout layout instead of importing a layout but in my real project, the layout I want to reuse is much more complicated and it makes sense to reuse.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're saying you just need a to display a `String` so instead of passing a `FirstLayoutViewModel` and `SecondLayoutViewModel`, you should pass the `String` to your `reusable_layout`.

```xml
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable name="myText" type="String> />
    </data>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text_to_replace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{myText}"/>
</layout>
```

More details:
[how to pass data in includes](https://medium.com/@elia.maracani/android-data-binding-passing-a-variable-to-an-include-d-layout-3567099b58f)

```kotlin
class MyViewModel1 : ViewModel {
    
    private val _myLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val myLiveData: LiveData<String>
        get() = _myLiveData

    init {
        //Assign MyLiveData
    }
}

class MyViewModel2 : ViewModel {
    
    private val _mySecondLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val mySecondLiveData: LiveData<String>
        get() = _mySecondLiveData

    init {
        //Assign MyLiveData
    }
}
```

**FirstLayout**:

```xml
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="MyViewModel1"/>
    </data>
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
      <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/title_one"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="First layout title"/>
      <include
          layout="@layout/reusable_layout"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:myText="@{viewModel.myLiveData}"
           />
  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**SecondLayout**:

```xml
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="MyViewModel2"/>
    </data>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
      <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/title_one"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="First layout title"/>
      <include
          layout="@layout/reusable_layout"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:myText="@{viewModel.mySecondLiveData}"
           />
  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: But the string I want to use is in LiveData objects, within separate ViewModels.

Comment: See the updated answer, you're not passing a `ViewModel` to your reusable layout but only the `String` you need